# How to put MATLAB GUI made from GUIDE on a website?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I used MATLAB's GUIDE tool to create an application which takes 3 user inputs, has a button, when pressed plots a graph.

It's a simple program, but I want to put this on a website so that I can use it there.

Is there an easy way to do this which doesn't require too much programming?

EDIT: I can export it as a java or .net package if that helps me in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I think deploying GUIDE GUI directly to web is not possible.
You can use MATLAB Compiler to create .NET assembly or JAR file so that you can call it from your web application.

http://in.mathworks.com/products/matlab-compiler-sdk/index.html

Comment: Thanks so much. Once I have the .net or jar, can I get some help on how I can 'call that from my web application'? Let's assume I have a wordpress website.

Comment: you can only integrate MATLAB functions with .NET,Java or Python based applicaion and for that you need combinations of api . You can refer official documentation for coding standards and steps to integrate.http://in.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/index.html